# Change of Basis over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

$[v ]_B$ coordinate vector of v with respect to $B$ 
$[v ]_C$ coordinate vector of v with respect to $C$ 
${}_C[ Id_V ]_B$ change of basis matrix from $B$ to $C$

For example we have the following set of vectors in $\mathbb{Z_3^3}$ 
$B$ = {[1  0 2]${^T}$, [2  1  1]${^T}$ , [1  1 1]${^T}$} 
$C$ = {[1  1  1]${^T}$ ,[2  1  1]${^T}$ , [1  1  2]${^T}$} 
How can I compute the change of basis from $B$ to $C$ using the following formula:
${}_C[ Id_V ]_B  [v ]_B = [ v ]_C$  where , 
${}_C[ Id_V ]_B = [ [b_1]_C \cdots  [b_n]_C]$ 
Again $V$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z_3^3}$ and $Id_V : V \rightarrow V$

I think the formula is a fairly simple computation but the confusing part is the change of coordinate vectors , namely ${}_C[ Id_V ]_B = [ [b_1]_C \cdots  [b_n]_C]$. Also, I have checked that the given set of vector do form basis of $\mathbb{Z_3^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a strange notation.

Note that ${}_I[Id_V]_B=B$, where $I$ is the unit matrix, and then ${}_C[Id_V]_I=C^{-1}$ and ${}_C[Id_V]_B = {}_C[Id_V]_I \, {}_I[Id_V]_B=C^{-1}B$.

Comment: So I can’t avoid taking the inverse to change the basis? Because I was wondering that with the formula that I provided in the question, perhaps it could be done without involving inverses.

Comment: ${}_C[Id_V]_B$ and ${}_B[Id_V]_C$ have to be inverses of each other, so taking the inverse has to be involved somehow (unless this is just a constant unit matrix, which is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

${}_C[Id_V]_B = {}_C[Id_V]_I \, {}_I[Id_V]_B=C^{-1}B$

= $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \:0\: 2 \\ 1 \:2\: 0 \\ 0 \:2\: 1\end{bmatrix}$      $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \:2\: 1 \\ 0 \:1\: 1 \\ 2 \:1\: 1\end{bmatrix}$

=$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \:0\: 1 \\ 1 \:1\: 0 \\ 2 \:0\: 0\end{bmatrix}$